# Rename [sqlx] tag to [go-sqlx]

Tags: support, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

The [sqlx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlx) (188) and the rapidly growing [rust-sqlx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust-sqlx) (122) groups tend to often be confused - I had to re-tag about 15 of the mis-tagged ones from `sqlx` to `rust-sqlx`. Since the numbers are somewhat converging, please rename `sqlx` into `go-sqlx` for clarity. Thanks!

See also [How to rename a tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87437/how-to-rename-a-tag)